# Iterating List using DAO Java

Tags: java, jsp, loops, iterator, dao

In this code I declared a variable that contains the values of the List which is the `acode`. I can see the values in this List, but I don't know how to iterate over the values using the `adao.adao.findAllacctDesc(**acode**)`. How can i iterate over this list, so that the options show the values?

Here is the code:

```
<%
TblTaxTypeDAO tdao = DAOFactory.getDaoManager(TblTaxType.class);
TblAccountCodesDAO adao = DAOFactory.getDaoManager(TblAccountCodes.class);

List<TblTaxType> acode =  null;

String tcode = request.getParameter("taxt");
String bcode = request.getParameter("bfns");


acode = tdao.findAllAcctCode(bcode, tcode);
Debugger.print(acode);

List<TblAccountCodes> acctdesclist = null;
acctdesclist = adao.findAllacctDesc(acode); <= Having error in this line because acode is a list not a string.

String acctdescoptions = "";

if( acctdesclist!=null) {
if( acctdesclist.size()>0 ) {
for(int i=0; i<acctdesclist.size();i++) {
TblAccountCodes acctcode = (TblAccountCodes) acctdesclist.get(i);
acctdescoptions += "<option value='"+acctcode.getAcctCode()+"'>"+acctcode.getAcctDesc()+"</option>";                                        
acctcode = null;
    }
  }
}

adao = null;
acctdesclist = null;
%>
<%=acctdescoptions%>
```

Comment: Don't mix Java and HTML. Use `jstl`.

Comment: I know that, but I just need this code. For this purpose only.

Comment: I suggest you don't think that way. Start forming good habits early on.

Comment: Ok I appreciate that.

Comment: I never see acode declared, what is it?  Also, this will not compile: Debugger.print(acode.);

Comment: Sorry, please see updated post.

Answer (score 0):

change

```
List<TblAccountCodes> acctdesclist = null;
acctdesclist = adao.findAllacctDesc(acode); <= Having error in this line because acode is   a list not a string.
```

by

```
List<TblAccountCodes> acctdesclist = null;
for(TblTaxType T:acode){
acctdesclist.add(adao.findAllacctDesc(T.getString))
}
```

Is this what you want?

where getString is the function in TblTaxType where you return the string you need.

Comment: Error: `The method findAllacctDesc(String) in the type TblAccountCodesDAO is not applicable for the arguments 
 (TblTaxType)`

Comment: Error:`The method add(TblAccountCodes) in the type List<TblAccountCodes> is not applicable 
  for the arguments (List<TblAccountCodes>)`

Comment: If you want me to help you more, you need to supply the whole code please

Comment: What exact codes you need? I believed I already gave the needed codes.